# htaccess issue with URL masking

Tags: htaccess, drupal

I am attempting to mask an URL using an htaccess file to only show the root URL.
This is a Drupal 7 website, so I want the URLs to look like the following:

```
Main page:
  http://www.site1.com
Drupal content:
  http://www.site1.com/content/....
```

There is also a test site that should appear as:

```
Test site:
  http://www.site1.com/site1-test
Test content:
  http://www.site1.com/site1-test/content/...
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
 public_html/
            |--site1/
            |--site1-test/
```

Here is the htaccess file I've been working on in `public_html/.htaccess`.  It mainly works, however there is a small issue.  When I visit site1.com the URL appears as I want, however whenever I click any content it shows `site1.com/site1/...` instead of hiding the extra subdirectory.  This is based on a [prior StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153189/how-to-root-multiple-domains-to-multiple-subfolders).

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#========================================================================
# FIRST Handle the http requests first before removing the additional url junk
#========================================================================
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com/site1-test$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1-test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1-test/$1

#==========================================================
# SECOND Remove the additional url junk once the new url is loaded
#==========================================================
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?rg$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site1/index.php
```

Previously I'd updated the `$base_url` variable in the settings.php file, however that seemed to break my themes unless if I pointed it directly to `site1.com/site1`, rather than to `site1.`  At present, there is no defined `$base_url.`

Comment: "whenever I click any content it shows site1.com/site1/... instead of hiding the extra subdirectory" - Presumably your HTML links reflect your desired URL structure?

Comment: They currently do, yes.  Though to be fair, the links are auto-generated by Drupal.

Comment: That would seem to suggest that something else (maybe Drupal?) is redirecting? Just to clarify, the link is showing `site1.com/content`, but the URL in the address shows `site1.com/site1/content`? If you check the network traffic, you presumably see the redirection?

Comment: The link is also showing site1.com/site1/content, and the URL reflects that.   Updating `$base_url` in Drupal causes the link to show the appropriate content, however that breaks the Drupal theme.

Comment: "The link is also showing site1.com/site1/content" - That's what I was asking in the first comment. If the link is showing the _undesirable_ URL then that needs to be fixed first (in Drupal). (Otherwise you would need to set up external redirects in .htaccess as well.) If the Drupal theme breaks when you change the URL then that would seem to be a "problem" with the theme? When you say "break", are you referring to the CSS?

Comment: Good point.  Yes, it appears to be a CSS issue when I fix the links.

Comment: Actually, updating that `$base_url` introduces all kinds of problems...restricted pages, broken login system, etc.